# Haskell :: Aeson :: parse ADT based on field value

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I'm using an external API which returns JSON responses. One of the responses is an array of objects and these objects are identified by the field value inside them. I'm having some trouble understanding how the parsing of such JSON response could be done with Aeson.

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
newtype Content = Content { content :: [Media] } deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON Content

data Media =
  Video { objectClass :: Text
        , title :: Text } |
  AudioBook { objectClass :: Text
            , title :: Text }
```

In API documentation it is said that the object can be identified by the field *objectClass* which has value "video" for our *Video* object and "audiobook" for our *AudioBook* and so on. Example JSON:

```
[{objectClass: "video", title: "Some title"}
,{objectClass: "audiobook", title: "Other title"}]
```

The question is how can this type of JSON be approached using Aeson?

```
instance FromJSON Media where
  parseJSON (Object x) = ???
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You basically need a function `Text -> Text -> Media`:

```
toMedia :: Text -> Text -> Media
toMedia "video"     = Video "video"
toMedia "audiobook" = AudioBook "audiobook"
```

The `FromJSON` instance is now really simple (using `<$>` and `<*>` from  `Control.Applicative`):

```
instance FromJSON Media where
    parseJSON (Object x) = toMedia <$> x .: "objectClass" <*> x .: "title"
```

However, at this point you're redundant: the `objectClass` field in `Video` or `Audio` doesn't give you more information than the actual type, so you might remove it:

```
data Media = Video     { title :: Text }
           | AudioBook { title :: Text }

toMedia :: Text -> Text -> Media
toMedia "video"     = Video
toMedia "audiobook" = AudioBook
```

Also note that `toMedia` is partial. You probably want to catch invalid `"objectClass"` values:

```
instance FromJSON Media where
    parseJSON (Object x) = 
        do oc <- x .: "objectClass"
           case oc of
               String "video"     -> Video     <$> x .: "title"
               String "audiobook" -> AudioBook <$> x .: "title"
               _                  -> empty

{- an alternative using a proper toMedia
toMedia :: Alternative f => Text -> f (Text -> Media)
toMedia "video"     = pure Video
toMedia "audiobook" = pure AudioBook
toMedia _           = empty

instance FromJSON Media where
    parseJSON (Object x) = (x .: "objectClass" >>= toMedia) <*> x .: "title"
-}
```

And last, but not least, remember that [valid JSON](http://json.org/) uses strings for the name.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about valid JSON, I was simply typing my question in without looking it up and failed to provide correct JSON representation.

Comment: @ksaveljev: It's ok, it's just a reminder, since `{ key1 : value1, key2: value2, ... }` is valid in *JavaScript* even if the keys aren't strings.

Answer (score 5):

The default translation for a data type like:

```
data Media = Video     { title :: Text }
           | AudioBook { title :: Text }
             deriving Generic
```

is actually very close to what you want. (For the simplicity of my examples, I define `ToJSON` instances and encode the examples to see what kind of JSON we get.)

### aeson, default

So, with the default instance we have (view [the complete source file](http://hub.darcs.net/imz/constructor-as-tag_aeson-default/browse/constructor-as-tag-aeson.hs) which produces this output):

```
[{"tag":"Video","title":"Some title"},{"tag":"AudioBook","title":"Other title"}]
```

Let's see whether we can get even closer with custom options...

### aeson, custom `tagFieldName`

With custom [options](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Options):

```
mediaJSONOptions :: Options
mediaJSONOptions = 
    defaultOptions{ sumEncoding = 
                        TaggedObject{ tagFieldName = "objectClass"
                                    -- , contentsFieldName = undefined
                                    }
                  }

instance ToJSON Media
    where toJSON = genericToJSON mediaJSONOptions
```

we get:

```
[{"objectClass":"Video","title":"Some title"},{"objectClass":"AudioBook","title":"Other title"}]
```

(Think yourself what you want to do with an undefined field in the real code.)

### aeson, custom `constructorTagModifier`

Adding

```
              , constructorTagModifier = fmap Char.toLower
```

to `mediaJSONOptions` gives:

```
[{"objectClass":"video","title":"Some title"},{"objectClass":"audiobook","title":"Other title"}]
```

**Great!** Exactly what you specified!

### decoding

Simply add an instance with the same options to be able to decode from this format:

```
instance FromJSON Media
    where parseJSON = genericParseJSON mediaJSONOptions
```

Example:

```
*Main> encode example
"[{\"objectClass\":\"video\",\"title\":\"Some title\"},{\"objectClass\":\"audiobook\",\"title\":\"Other title\"}]"
*Main> decode $ fromString "[{\"objectClass\":\"video\",\"title\":\"Some title\"},{\"objectClass\":\"audiobook\",\"title\":\"Other title\"}]" :: Maybe [Media]
Just [Video {title = "Some title"},AudioBook {title = "Other title"}]
*Main>
```

[Complete source file](http://hub.darcs.net/imz/test-haskell-aeson-constructor-as-tag_decoding/browse/constructor-as-tag-aeson.hs).

### generic-aeson, default

To get a more complete picture, let's also look at what [`generic-aeson`](https://github.com/silkapp/generic-aeson) package would give (at [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-aeson)). It has also nice default translations, different in some respects from those from `aeson`.

Doing

```
import Generics.Generic.Aeson -- from generic-aeson package
```

and defining:

```
instance ToJSON Media
    where toJSON = gtoJson
```

gives the result:

```
[{"video":{"title":"Some title"}},{"audioBook":{"title":"Other title"}}]
```

So, it's different from all what we've seen when using `aeson`.

generic-aeson's options ([Settings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-aeson-0.2.0.2/docs/Generics-Generic-Aeson.html#t:Settings)) are not interesting for us (they allow only to strip a prefix).

([The complete source file](http://hub.darcs.net/imz/test-haskell-aeson-constructor-as-tag_generic-aeson/browse/constructor-as-tag-aeson.hs).)

### aeson, ObjectWithSingleField

Apart from lower-casing the first letter of the constructor names, `generic-aeson`'s translation seems similar to an option available in `aeson`:

Let's try this:

```
mediaJSONOptions = 
    defaultOptions{ sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField
                  , constructorTagModifier = fmap Char.toLower
                  }
```

and yes, the result is:

```
[{"video":{"title":"Some title"}},{"audiobook":{"title":"Other title"}}]
```

### the rest of options: (aeson, `TwoElemArray`)

One available [option](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Options) for `sumEncoding` has been left out from consideration above, because it gives an array which is not quite similar to the JSON representation asked about. It's `TwoElemArray`. Example:

```
[["video",{"title":"Some title"}],["audiobook",{"title":"Other title"}]]
```

is given by:

```
mediaJSONOptions = 
    defaultOptions{ sumEncoding = TwoElemArray
                  , constructorTagModifier = fmap Char.toLower
                  }
```