# Parsing data types with all nullary constructors using generic decode

Tags: haskell, generics, aeson

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data CharClass = Fighter | Rogue | Wizard deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON CharClass
instance ToJSON CharClass
```

I can encode values of this type:

```
*Main> encode Fighter
"\"Fighter\""
```

But round-tripping doesn't work:

```
*Main> eitherDecode $ encode Fighter
Left "Failed reading: satisfy"
*Main> :t eitherDecode $ encode Fighter
eitherDecode $ encode Fighter :: FromJSON a => Either String a
```

It looks a lot like [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143342/haskell-adts-with-aeson), but adding the expected type doesn't work:

```
*Main> eitherDecode $ encode Fighter :: Either String CharClass 
Left "Failed reading: satisfy"
```

Interestingly, it does work for `fromJSON`/`toJSON`:

```
*Main> fromJSON $ toJSON Fighter :: Result CharClass
Success Fighter
```

Making at least one of the constructors non-nullary also makes things work, like if I do this:

```
data CharClass = Fighter Int | Rogue | Wizard deriving (Generic, Show)
```

And then try to round-trip again:

```
*Main> decode $ encode (Fighter 0) :: Maybe CharClass
Just (Fighter 0)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but attempting to trace this through the generic code made my head spin.

Comment: have you tried adding a derived `Read` instance?

Comment: Deriving `Read` makes no difference, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not too surprised, but it was the first thing I would have tried. Unfortunately I have no experience with using the default implementation of any method in the `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` classes (I've always implemented them manually in order to fit a pre-existing schema)

Comment: I think you forgot to exorcise the demons. Check with your local clergy.

Comment: You should try asking ghci for the types of those nothings.

Comment: Also, you might want to try `eitherDecode` with a type signature to check for encode/decode mismatches.

Comment: Good call @dfeuer - I've added `eitherDecode` and `:t` information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of aeson that `stack` installed on my machine was from the 0.8 series, and in aeson 0.8 or earlier, [only objects and arrays were parsed at the root level](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.9.0.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Parser.html#v:json).

Answer (score 3):

JSON is fundamentally a collection of key-value pairs, where values can be a few primitive types or another collection of key-value pairs.  Nullary types just don't fit in very well with the whole idea of being JSON entities by themselves.  However, they work fine when placed within other types that mesh well with the JSON concept.

```
data F = F { a :: CharClass, b :: CharClass }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON F
instance ToJSON F
```

This looks more like the sort of key-value collection JSON was designed for.

```
*Main> let x = F Fighter Rogue
*Main> x
F {a = Fighter, b = Rogue}
*Main> decode $ encode x :: Maybe F
Just (F {a = Fighter, b = Rogue})
```

Comment: Interesting, but it makes incremental testing annoying when you can't parse your base cases.

Comment: Check the [json spec](http://json.org/).  The top-level parsing element is an `object`, but nullary types only fit in as a `value`.  The automatically derived parser only knows how to parse an `object`.

Comment: Sure, but check the [docs for aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.9.0.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Parser.html#v:json). "In aeson 0.8 and earlier, it parsed only object or array types, in conformance with the now-obsolete RFC 4627." Looks like it's meant to be able to parse things that aren't objects at the top level?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.9.0.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Parser.html#v:value

Answer (score 2):

In aeson 0.9, `decode` uses `value` parser. So nullable object (represented as string) at top-level will work.

For 0.8 the below example works. I don't know why `decodeWith` isn't exposed.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Control.Applicative
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Parser
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 (endOfInput, skipSpace)
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Lazy as L

data CharClass = Fighter | Rogue | Wizard deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ToJSON CharClass
instance FromJSON CharClass

decodeWith p to s =
    case L.parse p s of
      L.Done _ v -> case to v of
                      Success a -> Just a
                      _         -> Nothing
      _          -> Nothing
{-# INLINE decodeWith #-}

valueEOF = value <* skipSpace <* endOfInput

decodeValue :: (FromJSON a) => L.ByteString -> Maybe a
decodeValue = decodeWith valueEOF fromJSON

main :: IO ()
main = print (decodeValue (encode Fighter) :: Maybe CharClass)
```